# Zoom Api - I can't update a meeting

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, zoom-sdk

I am trying to update a meeting using [Zoom API](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/) but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to do a PATCH request using [eleague oauth2 client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) like this:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../config.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$start_time = $_POST['start_time'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$agenda = $_POST['agenda'];

$params = array(
        'topic' => $topic,
        'type' => $type,
        'start_time' => $start_time,
        'duration' => $duration,
        'agenda' => $agenda,
        'password' => '123456'
);

$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => CONEXAO_API['clientId'],    
    'clientSecret'            => CONEXAO_API['clientSecret'],   
    'redirectUri'             => CONEXAO_API['redirect_url'],
    'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://zoom.us/oauth/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me'
]);

$options['body'] = json_encode( $params );
$options['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
$options['headers']['Accept'] = 'application/json';


$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest( 'PATCH', 
        'https://api.zoom.us/v2/meetings/'.$id,
        unserialize($_SESSION['token']), 
        $options
);

$retorno =  $provider->getParsedResponse($request);

var_dump($retorno);
```

I'm getting an empty response, and I'm not sure what is missing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically the response given by the api is blank or just meeting updated which isn't in json format. So in case you want to check whether its working go to zoom meeting panel and open the meeting which you are updating using api and run the api and check the meeting is updated in zoom meeting panel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method **getParsedResponse** for some reason is not returning any message. But the script is working, it's updating the meeting the way it supposed to.

If I get the response using the method **getResponse** I can see the statusCode **204**, which means that everything went ok.